# Combine Images in android

Tags: android, image, bitmap

how to merge two images in android by programming in java and save in external SD Card or some where else.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by merging two images ?

Comment: i have two different images  i want to make program in android that combine this images as one images by programming .

Comment: Once again what do you mean by combine. If you have two images you want to produce single image that is concatenation of the two or you want to sum the pixel values somehow. If the first image is bigger then the second ? Please explain in more details

Comment: Ketan's answer link is broken.

Comment: sorry about that look like his blog is removed.

Comment: @ChiragRaval I have posted the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out this code.

```
private static final String TAG = "JoinImage";
private Bitmap mBackImage, mTopImage, mBackground; 
private BitmapDrawable mBitmapDrawable;
private static String mTempDir;
private String mSavedImageName = null; 
private FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = null;
private Canvas mCanvas;
```

in `onCreate()`

```
//Create folder in SDCard to store newly generated image
mTempDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/TestTemp/";
File mTempFile = new File(mTempDir);
if(!mTempFile.exists()) {
    mTempFile.mkdirs();
}
//File name 
mSavedImageName = "Test.png";
//Width = 604, Height = 1024 Change as per your requirement
mBackground = Bitmap.createBitmap(100, 100, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
//Put back and top images in your res folder
mBackImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.launcher);
mTopImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

mCanvas = new Canvas(mBackground);
mCanvas.drawBitmap(mBackImage, 0f, 0f, null);
mCanvas.drawBitmap(mTopImage, 12f, 12f, null);

try {
    mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(mBackground);
    Bitmap mNewSaving = mBitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
    String FtoSave = mTempDir + mSavedImageName;
    File mFile = new File(FtoSave);
    mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
    mNewSaving.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 95, mFileOutputStream);
    mFileOutputStream.flush();
    mFileOutputStream.close();
} catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "FileNotFoundExceptionError " + e.toString());
} catch(IOException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "IOExceptionError " + e.toString());
}
Log.i(TAG, "Image Created");
```

in `Manifest`add this uses-permission `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`

Answer (score 8):

Try below code

```
private Bitmap joinImages(File first, File second)
{
    Bitmap bmp1, bmp2;
    bmp1 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(first.getPath());
    bmp2 = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(second.getPath());
    if (bmp1 == null || bmp2 == null)
        return bmp1;
    int height = bmp1.getHeight();
    if (height < bmp2.getHeight())
        height = bmp2.getHeight();

    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth() + bmp2.getWidth(), height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, 0, 0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, bmp1.getWidth(), 0, null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
```

Comment: where on which line it says and are you using this code exactly?

Comment: at canvas line it show error any way thank i got answer from  this link [http://ketankantilal.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-combine-images-and-store-to.html  thank for help.

Comment: Yes We saw Ketan's code and figured out we need to pass Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 this attribute to bitmap which we set in background and it solved my problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: actually the problem is that the bitmap you are trying to join is immutable that why earlier the code is getting the config of the bitmap that you are supplying