# How to Add Picture Frames to Image?

Tags: android, image, surfaceview, android-custom-view, picasso

I am trying to achieve frames functionality , such that if i provide an image After Capturing/retrieving from Gallery ,i have done this part , now where i am stuck is `How can i merge two images with respect to frame image accordingly!!`

Now solution for combining two images is clearly given [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5948886/combine-images-in-android) and [Here](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Combining_2_Images_in_Android_using_Canvas)

But they are not explaining the behaviour of adjusting one image with another such that in my case , Here are some examples:

[image: image with frame1]

[image: image with frame2]

`I am already using Libraries like picasso and EasyImage so if they can help?`

**Edit:**

Test Frame example [image: test frame]

Comment: You can rotate, translate and scale bitmap to fit image's bitmap and frame's bitmap. here is example of rotating, translating and scaling bitmap http://android--code.blogspot.jp/2015/11/android-how-to-rotate-bitmap-on-canvas.html

Comment: @nshmura it's not that simple , what if how can anyone be sure that image will be adjusted by just using rotate , and transforming ?

Comment: I think we can do with rotate, translate and scale. Can you post your frame image?

Comment: @nshmura added a frame in question

Comment: anyone Here who could help please ?

Comment: I will try with this frame image.

Comment: This frame image dose not have transparent area. Can you make transparent the picture area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made example. Please refer this repository.
https://github.com/nshmura/TestFrame/

`Frame` class merges picture's bitmap and frame's bitmap.

```
public class Frame {

    //filename of frame
    private String mFrameName;

    //Rect of picture area in frame
    private final Rect mPictureRect;

    //degree of rotation to fit picture and frame.
    private final float mRorate;

    public Frame(String frameName,int left, int top, int right, int bottom, float rorate) {
        mFrameName = frameName;
        mPictureRect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
        mRorate = rorate;
    }

    public Bitmap mergeWith(Context context, Bitmap pictureBitmap) {
        Bitmap frameBitmap = AssetsUtil.getBitmapFromAsset(context, mFrameName);

        Bitmap.Config conf = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBitmap.getWidth(), frameBitmap.getHeight(), conf);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

        Matrix matrix = getMatrix(pictureBitmap);
        canvas.drawBitmap(pictureBitmap, matrix, null);

        canvas.drawBitmap(frameBitmap, 0, 0, null);

        return bitmap;

    }

    Matrix getMatrix(Bitmap pictureBitmap) {
        float widthRatio = mPictureRect.width() /  (float) pictureBitmap.getWidth();
        float heightRatio = mPictureRect.height() / (float) pictureBitmap.getHeight();

        float ratio;

        if (widthRatio > heightRatio) {
            ratio = widthRatio;

        } else {
            ratio = heightRatio;
        }

        float width = pictureBitmap.getWidth() * ratio;
        float height = pictureBitmap.getHeight() * ratio;
        float left = mPictureRect.left - (width - mPictureRect.width()) / 2f;
        float top = mPictureRect.top - (height - mPictureRect.height()) / 2f;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postRotate(mRorate);
        matrix.postScale(ratio, ratio);
        matrix.postTranslate(left, top);

        return matrix;
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
//This is sample picture.
//Please take picture form gallery or camera.
Bitmap pictureBitmap = AssetsUtil.getBitmapFromAsset(this, "picture.jpg");

//This is sample frame.
// the number of left, top, right, bottom is the area to show picture.
// last argument is degree of rotation to fit picture and frame.
Frame frameA = new Frame("frame_a.png", 113, 93, 430, 409, 4);
Bitmap mergedBitmap = frameA. mergeWith(this, pictureBitmap);

//showing result bitmap
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.setImageBitmap(mergedBitmap);
```

Result is below:

[image]

Comment: What does , left, right,top,bottom, integers works , i am trying to make it work with my pictures but unable to do so ,my picture is showing nothing other than frame image

Comment: Can you post your pictures which was not drawn.

Comment: Thanks it worked , just not very comfortable with `Rect` class yet , if you have any good material regarding size handling of `Rect` class that would be great

Comment: Can you please update link as its not found @nshmura